Can we add custom functionality to spring boot admin 3.3
so I just used spring boot admin for monitoring purposes but I want to also add some custom functionalities like viewing the application.properties file in the admin dashboard. Is it possible to do so? If yes then how?
I saw this question and yet I haven't implemented anything Spring boot admin add custom tab

There already exists a view to show all config props of a spring boot application. It utilizes the standard configprops actuator endpoint. So, whenever your application exposes this endpoint, you should find a ‘Configuration Properties’ view out-of-the-box.
Spring Boot Admin offers many customisation options (e.g. custom views). The documentation for this is very detailed (https://docs.spring-boot-admin.com/current/customize_ui.html).
Apart from that, there are numerous samples in the repository that should cover pretty much every case (https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/tree/master/spring-boot-admin-samples).
If you want to add a custom tab or submenu for instance, you should have a look at these samples: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/tree/master/spring-boot-admin-samples/spring-boot-admin-sample-custom-ui
